# What does WARNING: [something] overlaps [something] in Windows Debugger mean?

Tags: windbg, virtual-machine, kernel

I am editing the Windows Research Kernel (WRK) for part of a uni project, and occasionally when I start up the virtual machine running my kernel, the Windows Debugger says things like:

```
WARNING: rdpdr overlaps raspptp_baa74000
WARNING: ks overlaps rdpdr_baa26000
WARNING: ks overlaps raspptp_baa74000
WARNING: update_baa11000 overlaps ks_ba9fe000
WARNING: update_baa11000 overlaps rdpdr_baa26000
WARNING: tcpip overlaps tcpip_ba83e000
```

What does this actually mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This usually happens when the kernel debugger misses events (such as shutdown or module unload).  The warning means that the debugger just received a module load event for a driver in a range that overlaps another driver (the overlap is usually not real, it is just that the debugger thinks there is a overlap because it did not know about the unload).

This is fixed by using `.reload`.