# Overlapped_module Winbdg

Tags: debugging, windbg

I am new to windbg and i am trying to investigate a crash dump and I found out this statement while analyzing the dump.

`Overlapped_Module: Address regions for time.dll and date.dll overlap.`

Can any one explain what it means and whether it is the reason for the crash

Answer (score 2):

It means that the address regions for those dlls overlap which should not really happen.

There are a few potential causes, firstly the dump may have been created [incorrectly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11097652/windows-application-debugging), secondly the [kernel may have received the load events but missed the unload events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051492/what-does-warning-something-overlaps-something-in-windows-debugger-mean), you can also confirm whether these modules are loaded at all by calling `lm` and seeing if `time.dll` and `date.dll` are loaded/unloaded/deferred.

Comment: This can also happen when you're debugging a 32-bit process with a dump taken from a 64-bit tool.  This creates a WOW dump, which exhibits the symptoms you mention.

Comment: @SteveJohnson Yes that is linked to in my answer